# How to allow to only one dot?

Tags: regex

I have regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9,.]*$
```

but I want to allow only one dot in string. I want to not allow the placement of links.

How to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9,]*\.?[a-zA-Z0-9,]*$
```

Btw, you can also shorten the regex by doing:

```
^[a-z\d,]*\.?[a-z\d,]*$   (using insensitive flag)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/xC4cP1/1)**

[image]

Comment: Just as I was typing: "Any set of characters excluding the dot, followed by an optional dot, followed by any set of characters excluding the dot." Is an empty string allowed? If not, add a lookahead as the first test.

Answer (score 1):

the following will limit the . to one or zero

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9,]*[.]{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9,]*$
```